# Laptop Monitor stuck on Blank

Tags: laptop, display

I have an Asus Vivobook laptop, which has a function key to turn off the monitor. When I hold down the "function" key and the "F7" key, the monitor is turned off, and the system still runs normally. To turn it back on, I use the same keys.

I use this to save power without putting my computer to sleep. But for some reason if I leave it off for a long time, it gets stuck on the "Off" state, and I can't use the Fn + F7 keys to switch it back on normally. This means I have to restart my computer every time this happens to get it working again.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening & how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Disable 'Turn off the display' in power options and try again, post results

Comment: Where exactly do I find the "Turn off the display" option in power options?

Comment: Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options - Change Plan Settings

Comment: It already was on off, so what should I do now?

Comment: Can you go into BIOS and tell me what options there are under Graphic.. is there a Repost video on S3 resume option there... Any options in the BIOS about C-States...

Comment: The only option under Graphics (and anything related) is the amount of pre-allocated RAM for the integrated graphics card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34349/discussion-between-setekh-and-aero-star).